# Qrcode reader with lazarsoft

Tags: javascript, qr-code, getusermedia

Ciao I'm using https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode, but I can not get the decoding of qrcode through the camera.
What I want to do is just get the decoding of reading qrcode

This is my code

HTML

```
 <video autoplay></video>
 <canvas id="qr-canvas"></canvas>
```

JS

```
        var video = document.querySelector('video');
        var constraints = 
        {
            audio: false,
            video: 
            {
              facingMode: { exact: "environment" },
              width: { min: 100, ideal: 400, max: 450 },
              height: { min: 100, ideal: 400, max: 450 }
            }
        }

        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
        .then(function(mediaStream) 
        {

          video.srcObject = mediaStream;
          video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) 
          {
            video.play();
          };

        }).catch(function(err) 
        { 
            console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
        });

        var qr_canvas = 
        document.getElementById('qr-canvas').getContext('2d');
        qr_canvas.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 400, 400);
        qrcode.decode();


        function readQR(a)
        {
            alert(a);
        }

        qrcode.callback = readQR;
```

Grazie

Answer (score 1):

Chrome does not support `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` any more. Please use `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(function(MediaDeviceInfo) { ... })` for your development, and you can reference my [project](https://github.com/licaomeng/js-qrcode-scanner) on github: https://github.com/licaomeng/js-qrcode-scanner